# Delete Jenkins build link from Github PR

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have got below two Jenkins build links in Github **PR**, the second one is the default PR build trigger

**Github PR section:**
[image]

**Jenkins configure section:**
[image]

The first one as marked above due to adding the branch name in the Jenkins configuration under `includes` section (as shown above).

So my question is, how can I delete the first one (marked in Github image) from the `Github` side. Because even after delete that branch under include list in the configuration (shown in the above Jenkins image), despite disappearing from the Jenkins it still shows in the `Github` PR.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that above was due to `git branch protections rules`.

In particular because below is enabled.

[image]